# TCP handshake not completing intermittently to specific Cloudflare node

Tags: apache-2.2, routing, tcp, cloudflare, tcpip

I have setup a webpage with Cloudflare that works nearly all of the time, except occasionally the TCP handshake fails with the `SYN+ACK` not making it to Cloudflare. On a packet capture from another machine on the network with the server, I can see the `SYN` arrive, the `SYN+ACK` is sent, but no `ACK` arrives, instead retried `SYN` packets come in and are replied to (see Wireshark log below). Users eventually receive a 522 Timeout error page from Cloudflare.

From the data I have gathered this only happens when users get routed through the Chicago Cloudflare node, and is only affecting users in central Canada/US (no reports of any issues from the east or west coasts).

These users ARE able to access the site fine if they attempt to connect directly by IP address (bypassing Cloudflare), even while refreshing the Cloudflare domain continues to timeout.

Happy to provide any more information as needed, but being an intermittent issue, may be hard to reproduce again.

[image]